# Android Theme - "Cannot resolve symbol" error on statusBarColor item

Tags: android, material-design, themes

In my Android (API 30) app theme (file themes.xml) using MaterialComponents the "android:statusBarColor" works but displays the following error in red :*Cannot resolve symbol* 'android:statusBarColor'

You can reproduce this by creating a new android projet with the "Tabbed Activity" template :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppTest" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color.  IN RED - "Cannot resolve symbol" below  -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>  
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

In fact, all android items in themes produce this ***Cannot resolve symbol***, like :

```
<style name="ToolbarPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents">
    <!--   android:background below in RED-->
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

If any of you have any insight on this, it would be great.

Comment: android:statusBarColor is introduced in API level 21. And may be You are writing this code in default styles.xlm. You have to create styles.xml in values-v21 folder and there you can use this attribute without any error

Answer (score 1):

`android:statusBarColor` is introduced in API level 21.
So, If You are trying to use this property in default styles.xlm. You will get Cannot resolve symbol.

You can create styles.xml in values-v21 folder and there you can use this attribute without any error

Comment: After moving the themes.xml file from values to values-v21, the error still appears

Comment: Can you try invalidating cache and restarts ?

Comment: Same. You can reproduce this by creating a new android projet with the "Tabbed Activity" template (Android Studio Canary 4)